# Issue with import name(conflict app name with python module name) in celery

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, celery

I have an app in django as social(app name) also using 'social_django' module

but 'social_django' django have dependency module python 'social'

both having same name as 'social' due to this **autodiscover_tasks** giving wrong path for django app social

## installed app for django

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
  'social_django',
  'social'
]
```

## Steps to reproduce

add social_django in installed app also create django app with same name as social
now check path coming in fuction ***find_related_module*** at **/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/loaders/base.py**

```
the following line  is creating the bug 


pkg_path = importlib.import_module(package).__path__
```

## Expected behavior

expected path : **/home/user/workspace/project/social**

## Actual behavior

actual path:: **/lib/python3.5/site-packages/social**